# Custom theme logo

Tags: moodle

I have a setting  page in my custom theme with a logo setting :

```
$name = 'theme_xxx/logo';
$title = get_string('logo', 'theme_xxx');
$description = get_string('logodesc', 'theme_xxx');
$setting = new admin_setting_configstoredfile($name, $title, 
$description, 'logo');
$setting->set_updatedcallback('theme_reset_all_caches');
$settings->add($setting);
```

when I try to print out the logo

theme->settings->logo;?>

all I get is the name of the file but not the path. (/logo.png ) I have no Idea where the search is saved and what to do next.

Comment: Maybe you should check your `\public` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function:-

public function get_logo_url($maxwidth = null, $maxheight = 100) {
           global $CFG;

```
       return new moodle_url($url);
        }
       return parent::get_logo_url($maxwidth, $maxheight);
    }
```

this function is called in core_renderer.php to get the logo src.